# Correcting an error in interpreting CSV data

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am reworking the style of an excel stock portflio just for fun. Thus far I am able to grab data from Yahoo and put it into this form: [MsgBox Http.ResponseText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdeaN.png)

```
Dim URL As String: URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=snpohgkj"
Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
Http.Open "GET", URL, False
Http.Send
```

I am trying to set it up so that this data (above) gets put into each of the rows automatically. The first column will be filled in by the user for whatever he/she holds while the prices should be updated at the press of a button.

Currently whenever I refresh (this is linked to an activeX command button) and actually try to input the data in the excel file I get this: [FilledExcelExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgF1G.png)

The code for this part is:

```
Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbNewLine)
Dim sLine As String
Dim Values As Variant
For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
    sLine = Lines(i)
    If InStr(sLine, ",") > 0 Then
        Values = Split(sLine, ",")
        W.Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = Split(Split(sLine, Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34))(1), Chr(34))(0)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 5)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 4)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 3)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 6).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 2)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 7).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 1)
        W.Cells(i + 2, 8).Value = Values(UBound(Values))
    End If
Next i
W.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
```

Currently it appears as though it takes the proper name for first company but does not take the proper prices (looks like the last company's prices). I have been staring at this too long to find the error. Can anyone help put the correct data in the correct columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting the downloaded CSV on `vbNewLine` (aka `vbCrLf` or `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`) but the feed only uses a **linefeed** (aka `vbLf` or `Chr(10)`) as the line terminator. It's like the difference between a `<p>` vs a `<br/>` in HTML or an <kbd>Enter↵</kbd> over a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> in Microsoft Word.

```
Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbLf)
```

That should fix you up.

Essentially, the CSV was not being split into separate lines; it was just one long line. You were gathering the proper name from the beginning of that line and the stock prices from the end.